# Using EventMotion to move my paddle in a game of pong makes it unable to register collisions

Tags: haskell, collision, gloss

I am making a game of pong in haskell using gloss as my main library. The movement of the paddle controlled by player is tied to the x-coordinate of the mouse and is updated as it moves. The problem is, the ball doesn't register collision with the paddle while it is moving.

```
movePaddle :: Event -> Game -> Game
movePaddle (EventMotion (x,y)) g = g {nextPos = max 50 . min 750 $ (x+400)}
movePaddle _ g = g
```

movePaddle updates the next position of the player's paddle.

```
moveBall :: Game -> Float -> Game
moveBall g f = g {dir = dirn, ball = (xt, yt)}
```

Then, moveBall updates the direction in which the ball is moving, according to collision, and adjusts its coordinates.

```
updatePaddle :: Game -> Game
updatePaddle g = g {p1 = nextPos g}
```

Finally, updatePaddle updates the actual position of the paddle in the game.

My main function looks like this:

```
main = play
  (InWindow "pong" (800, 800) (300, 300))
  white
  60
  (Game 400 400 (400, 400) 0.72 5 400)
  gameDraw
  movePaddle
  updatePaddle . (flip moveBall)
```

I have tried updating the state only as the mouse moves, but then the ball won't move. If I let it move independently while also updating it during the event, it doubles its speed during the mouse movement. What can I do to create proper collision while still being able to move the paddle?

Edit: here's my `moveBall` code:

```
moveBall :: Float -> Game -> Game
moveBall f g = g {dir = dirn, ball = (xt, yt)}
 where
  xn = fst (ball g) + f * vel g * cos (dir g)
  yn = snd (ball g) + f * vel g * sin (dir g)
  dirx
    |(max 10 $ min 790 xn) == xn = 1
    |otherwise = -1
  diry
    |(max 10 $ min 790 yn) == yn = 1
    |otherwise = -1
  dirn
    |dirx == -1 = pi - diry * dir g
    |(diry == -1) && (dirx == 1) = diry * dir g
    |max (p1 g - 50) (min (p1 g + 50) xn) == xn && (yn <= 30) = paddleAngle (p1 g) xn
    |max (p2 g - 50) (min (p2 g + 50) xn) == xn && (yn >= 770) = - paddleAngle (p2 g) xn
    |otherwise = (dir g)
  xt = (f * vel g * cos dirn) + normalize (fst (ball g))
  yt = (f * vel g * sin dirn) + normalize (snd (ball g))
```

Comment: Well your `moveBall` doesn't use `f` at all (unless `dirn`, `xt`, and/or `yt` look at it -- please include their source), which seems like a red flag. Another red flag is that I don't see any collision-detection code at all. Either you're not telling us everything (please give us enough code that we can reproduce your problem) or the problem is even worse than you expected.

Comment: Sure thing! I changed things around a bit, but you can see my `moveBall` code in the edit to the original post. I should note that collision registers properly if the paddle isn't moving at all. It is only during event handling that it is somehow bypassed.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Turns out I was looking at the wrong paddle when registering collision and mixed up my coordinates, due to which collision for paddle 1 was being registered at the top of the screen, where paddle 2 is.